# JS file doesn't work

Tags: jscript

Here's the code in my JS file:

```
function arrayContains(array, value){
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
var possibleOptions = ["male", "female", "m", "f"];
var gender = prompt("What's your gender?","");
while(!arrayContains(possibleOptions, gender))
    gender = prompt("Invalid input. What's your gender?");
var name = prompt("What's your name?","");
var greeting = (gender == "male" || gender == "m") ? "Sup dude." : "Sup girl.";
alert("Hello, " + name + "! " + greeting);
```

The error I get:

```
Line: 5
char: 1
Object expected.
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: add `\` before `'`. I think `'` is your problem

Comment: [`your code`](http://jsfiddle.net/6c1qbq5t/) runs fine

Comment: That code runs without errors: http://jsfiddle.net/cscr3bvu/

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Microsoft JScript runtime runs this. Does it matter?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh I'm starting it by double-clicking on it in the desktop. Does it matter?

Comment: @AvivCohn — Yes, it matters. Most JavaScript is written to run in a web browser. We were assuming that is where you were running it.

Comment: [Here is a (sort-of) duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532138/prompt-dialog-in-wsh-using-jscript). There is no `prompt` global in the Windows Scripting Host.

Comment: `alert` and `prompt` are methods of the global window-object(which exists in a browser, but not when you run it via WSH)

Comment: @Quentin I see. I'd like to know: what's the standard way to code and run your Javascript code? Create a `.html` file and embed it in there? Or some other way?

Comment: @AvivCohn — JavaScript is a programming language. You can use it in many places. Client side in a web page is just the most common. The choice of which you use will mostly depend on what you need to achieve, not what other people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. As mentioned in comments, the w/cscript.exe script host does not support neither prompt() nor alert()
2. JScript arrays have no .IndexOf() method

You have to roll your own:

```
function arrayContains(array, value){
    for (var i = 0, e = array.length; i < e; ++i) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function prompt(p) {
    WScript.Stdout.Write(p + " > ");
    return WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
}

function alert(s) {
    WScript.Echo(s);
}

var possibleOptions = ["male", "female", "m", "f"];
var gender = prompt("What's your gender?","");
while(!arrayContains(possibleOptions, gender))
    gender = prompt("Invalid input. What's your gender?");
var name = prompt("What's your name?","");
var greeting = (gender == "male" || gender == "m") ? "Sup dude." : "Sup girl.";
alert("Hello, " + name + "! " + greeting);
```

output (console):

```
cscript 26073853.js
What's your gender? > neuter
Invalid input. What's your gender? > male
What's your name? > tarzan
Hello, tarzan! Sup dude.

cscript 26073853.js
What's your gender? > female
What's your name? > jane
Hello, jane! Sup girl.
```