# How can I prompt the user to enter a value in WSH JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prompt, wsh

I tried all the possible ways to enter a value from the user but none of those actually worked;
I wrote these codes in my notepad and saved with .js extension;

For example:

1.

```js
var input = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  .InputBox("Enter a value", "User Input", "");
```

2. 

```js
WScript.StdOut.Write("Enter a value: ");
var input = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```

3. 

```js
var input = prompt("Enter a value:");
```

4. 

```js
var number2 = Val(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine());
```

5. 

```js
var numberInput = shell.InputBox("Enter a number", "Factorial Calculator");
var number = parseInt(numberInput);
```

In most of these codes, the result says object does not support this property or method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prompt dialog in WSH using JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532138/prompt-dialog-in-wsh-using-jscript)